# Excel Formula-Return Value based on looking at two separate values (either/or)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using this formula to return a value from table below:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,USUB,1,FALSE)),"No Fruit Found",VLOOKUP(A2,USUB,2,FALSE))
```

USUB table has this data:

```
Fruit          Fruit Code   FruitID Location          CITY
Apple             APP          A    SEATTLE,WA          SEATTLE
Bananas           BAN          B    MODESTO,CA          MODESTO
Cherry            CHER         C    CHARLESTON,SC       CHARLESTON
Blackberrires     BLCKB        D    VICKSBURG,VA        VICKSBURG
Blueberries       BLUB         E    SAN DIEGO,CA        SAN DIEGO
Cantaloupe        CANT         F    GULF SHORES, AL     GULF SHORES
Grapes            GRP          G    NAPA VALLEY,CA      NAPA VALLEY
Peach             PCH          H    ATLANTA, GA         ATLANTA
Grapefruit        GRPFRT       I    FT LAUDERDALE, FL   FT LAUDERDALE
Pomegranate       POM          J    HONOLULU, HI        HONOLULU
Kiwi              KIW          K    SALEM, OR           SALEM
```

---

What formula would I use to first look at Fruit (USUB,1) and then Location (USUB,4) and return a value of Fruit Code (USUB,2) based on the criteria in the formula?

Comment: I don't understand, are there duplicates?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Not duplicates. Codes to use in place of the proper name.

Comment: The data has over 36,000 rows and over 40 columns.  The table is an example of what I might have in the datasheet.  So let's say in Column X, I want to make Fruit appear as the Fruit Code, I would need to look at Fruit and return a value of Fruit Code.  The problem I am having is on some of the data, the fruit is the same but with a different location.  So I need to search the fruit and location to come up with the Fruit Code. Sorry if this is confusing...

Comment: Probably an index - match with multiple criteria.

Comment: Does you location  and fruit have data validation?  the problem I see is misspellings on text strings returning invalid data.  I realize your example is generic, but look at `FT LAUDERDALE, FL` first it has a space between the city and state while others do not.  Also, could it be entered as `FORT LAUDERDALE, FL`.  If both are possible then searching on them would give errant information.

Comment: Scott thanks for the response. Yeah the data I gave you is generic, however some of the data I work with is like that and I usually have to work around it with replace. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would rarely suggest using the **DGET** function but this is a perfect example of when you can put it to good use. See the image below for the setup and use

[image]

the formula is:

```
=DGET(USUB,"Fruit Code",$A$1:$B$2)
```

It even has the added benefit that if you don't put a location it will just find the code for that fruit.

To catch the cases where there are no fruit & location combinations that match see below:

```
=IFERROR(DGET(USUB,"Fruit Code",$A$1:$B$2),"Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use an Index/Match with multiple criteria, entered as an array (with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>:

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH(H3&I3,$B$2:$B$13&$E$2:$E$13,0))`

(Adjust as necessary)

[image]

So, I was able to use a Fruit Code, and Location, to return an ID. The formula correctly resolves to `J`.  Is that what you were wanting? You basically just link `Match()` criteria with `&`, and then the ranges to match them in with `&`, and enter as array.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The sheet you are using is from the Name Manager and is on a different sheet than the data I am using.  Maybe I am over thinking this a bit. The Index/Match Formula didn't work for what I am trying to do.  Thank you again.

Comment: @CKoester - If you can set it up like the above, then you just need to change the references to the other sheet. When setting up the formula, you can just use the cursor to browse to the ranges, and it'll look there.

Answer (score 0):

This will look first to see if there are duplicates, if not it will return the correct ID regardless of what is entered for location.

If there is more than one of that fruit it will look to the location to find a match.

If in either case there is no match to be be found; either the fruit does not exist or the combination of fruit and location, when there are more than one fruit is not correct.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,H2)>1,IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH(1,INDEX(($D$2:$D$13=I2)*($A$2:$A$13=H2),),0)),"Multiple fruits but Location is wrong"),IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(H2,A:A,0)),"Not Found"))
```

For the reference to a table then use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(USUB[Fruit],H2)>1,IFERROR(INDEX(USUB[FruitID],MATCH(1,INDEX((USUB[Location]=I2)*(USUB[Fruit]=H2),),0)),"Multiple fruits but Location is wrong"),IFERROR(INDEX(USUB[FruitID],MATCH(H2,USUB[Fruit],0)),"Not Found"))
```

[image]